# date range check in single field date in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

suppose we have $start-date = 2013-09-23 and  $end-date = 2013-09-28 in controller. Now we have to get such field's date which are in between this range. example : table field Modified date : 2013-09-22 then this will be output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question it's not so clear but, if I understand, your asking something like:

```
$this->YourModel->find->(
    'all', 
    array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'YourModel.modified BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array($start-date, $end-date)
        )
    )
);
```